# Multi thread socket server shutdown by message Java

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, sockets, runnable

I have a multi threaded process that listens for messages and processes them. I want to be able to shut down the process if one of the messages received is "shutdown". I have implemented everything except the shutdown part.

I have a "Multi" class that extends `java.net.ServerSocket` with a `start`method. Inside...

```
java.net.Socket socket = null;
while (true) {
            try {
                socket = this.accept();
                new Thread(new SocketThread(socket, verifier, threading)).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

That SocketThread is another class that `implements Runnable`. Is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: If you’re using spring boot (recommended), you could use the built-in `/actuator/shutdown` endpoint

Comment: You should keep a list of running threads and, once a shutdown request has arrived, interrupt the threads (or wait until they finish). Use a flag to indicate whether the process is running and can start new threads, or recieved the shutdown request and can not serve requests any longer.

Comment: No. You only need to close the `ServerSocket` when you get this message. You should let all the currently running handlers run to completion, or to a read timeout. Force-closing them is brutal and pointless. @PavelSmirnov

Comment: @user207421, I didn't say "force-close", I said "interrupt".

Comment: what process do you want to shutdown? while (true) or SocketThread?

Comment: @dungtavan both, preferably. I used user207421's method and it seems to shut down the SocketThread but of course, true stays true. I need to change that somehow.

Comment: I don't know what this means. Either it shuts down the thread or it keeps looping. Not both at the same time. What should happen when you close the server socket is a socket exception 'socket closed', which you catch and break on.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Interrupting a `Socket` does nothing. It's not an `InterruptilbleChannel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had to do this before (as I don't usually find myself having to write a raw SocketServer much), but with this type of threading coordination I would try something like the following...

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting...");
            AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);
            Collection<Socket> sockets = new ArrayList<>();
            Collection<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
            try (ServerSocket socketServer = new ServerSocket(10101)) {
                System.out.println("Started.");
                while (running.get()) {
                    Socket socket = socketServer.accept();
                    sockets.add(socket);
                    if (running.get()) {
                        Thread thread = new Thread(new SocketHandler(socket, running));
                        thread.start();
                        threads.add(thread);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Stopping...");
                sockets.forEach(socket -> {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                threads.forEach(thread -> {
                    try {
                        thread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
            System.out.println("Stopped.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class SocketHandler implements Runnable {
        private final Socket socket;
        private final AtomicBoolean running;

        SocketHandler(Socket socket, AtomicBoolean running) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.running = running;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Client connected.");
                try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
                    boolean connected = true;
                    while (connected){
                        String command = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Command received: " + command);
                        if (command == null) {
                            connected = false;
                        } else if (command.equals("shutdown")) {
                            running.set(false);
                            try (Socket tmpSocket = new Socket("localhost", 10101)) {}
                        }
                        // process other commands
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Client disconnected.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** Changed the example to establish a connection to the server to cause it to unblock.

**Update:** Example code to handle the case where client disconnects. Credit to @user207421 for highlighting this (thanks).

**Update:** Changed the sample code to handle multiple client sockets / threads. Note that it will through an exception when you socket is closed which is currently just been printed to stderr. You'll probably want to handle that differently.

**Update:** You might also find code that simulates multiple client connections helpful:

```java
public class Clients {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> new NormalClient().run());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> new NormalClient().run());
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(() -> new NormalClient().run());
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(() -> new NormalClient().run());
        Thread thread5 = new Thread(() -> new ShutdownClient().run());
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();
        thread5.start();
    }
}

class NormalClient {
    void run() {
        try {
            try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 10101);
                 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    out.write("hello " + i);
                    out.newLine();
                    out.flush();
                    sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ShutdownClient {
    void run() {
        try {
            try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 10101);
                 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))) {

                sleep(8000);
                out.write("shutdown");
                out.newLine();
                out.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this almost worked. Unfortunately it's waiting for one more message before it shuts down. Maybe it's because of the clearing resources bit which I don't know how to do (this is kinda' my first dive in multithreading).  
Also the program doesn't stop running for some reason (and that's the purpose in the first place). I hope I am being specific enough...

Comment: Basically I am expecting ```Process finished with exit code 0``` and that doesn't happen even after the second iteration

Comment: @Crates I expect `interrupt()` on `callingThread` is not working (some Java APIs can't be interrupted when blocked). So `callingThread` remains blocked on `accept()`. As I mentioned in my answer, you might want to consider making a connection to the server instead of using `callingThread.interrupt()`.

Comment: @Crates Take a look at the updates. That should work a bit better.

Comment: This code gets an NPE when the peer closes the connection.

Comment: @user207421 I'm not that surprised. I'm not trying to provide a full implementation of a robust Raw Socket Sever (which I think is a bit beyond the point of Stack Overflow). Rather demonstrate the how one might coordinate between two threads. There are quite a few things left for the reader (e.g. proper management of socket resources). Let me take a quick look though...

Comment: [BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) will return null to indicate end of the stream. I can update the example to handle this case, but I would really recommend some thorough testing to know these cases will be handled properly.

Comment: @Alex, maybe I'm wrong but it will always jump to ```Socket socket = socketServer.accept();``` before it does anything on the thread. Also, when I try to connect to the server it says ```connection refused``` so my program still doesn't terminate, it just runs until the end, stops listening but keeps hanging there...

Comment: @Crates Looks like I messed up the shutdown logic when introducing handling for client disconnect: Incorrectly was using `!` when deciding whether to shut down the server. Removed that. Test should run successfully now.

Comment: @Crates Have you considered using [Netty](https://netty.io/) or something similar? In my experience working with these Java IO APIs can be quite cumbersome and require a fair bit of boilerplate code. I understand that there are many reasons why using a library might not be an option, but if it is, you might find you can build a more robust sever in fewer LoC.

Comment: @Alex I'll look into Netty. But it wasn't the ```!``` I didn't even notice that. I do get the ```Stopped.``` message. It's just hanging after that for some reason...

Comment: @Crates Are you sure you getting this behaviour from just running the sample code and the test? From what you've described it sounds like the main thread has exited, but another thread is still running. For a complete solution, when the main thread is exiting, it should cleanup any running threads and socket. As I mentioned that code is omitted for brevity. With a single client connection (which is what the test makes) that sends 'shutdown' as final command, the program should exit normally.

Comment: @ Crates Made an update that should support multiple connections and cleanup resources on shutdown. Also swapped out the test for some code that simulates multiple clients connecting with one that send a 'shutdown' command. Hope that works a bit better for you.

Comment: That stopped it going to ```.accept``` for the second time. I think there is something in my implementation that I don't understand since the program runs it's course but still doesn't stop once it reaches the end... I'll check with my collaborators on this and I'll come back to you once I get it working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Happy I could help a bit. With regard to the JVM not shutting down it sounds like there is a thread that is waiting on something. I don't see this when I run the example code myself. You might try asking the JVM to dump threads which will give you an stacktrace for all threads. In IntelliJ  IDEA this is pretty easy (see camera icon when running it) but there are lots of other options to get the JVM to do this if you're not using IntelliJ.